# service "kubernetes" deleted - accidentally deleted kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I accidentally deleted the kubernetes svc:

```
service "kubernetes" deleted
```

using:

```
 kubectl delete svc --all
```

what should I do? I was just trying to remove services so I could launch new ones.

Comment: I think you'll have to do etcd surgery, since IIRC Kubernetes remembers which ClusterIPs it has given out and will not let you assign `${service_cidr}.1` to the Service named `kubernetes`. You can certainly try along with some `--validate=false` and take your chances, but I'm pretty sure it won't work

Comment: I did the same yesterday, but for me the service is created again. I am not sure, how though.

Answer (score 11):

A bit theory first ;) 
Whenever you delete kubernetes svc, you also delete endpoint and this is where 
[Reconciler](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/master/controller.go#L276) comes in. It is actually a controller manager for the core bootstrap Kubernetes controller loops, which manage creating the "**kubernetes**" service, the
"**default**", "**kube-system**" and "**kube-public**" namespaces, and provide the IP repair check on service IPs.

So, in healthy clusters **default.kubernetes** service should be automatically recreated by controller manager.

If it's not, I'd recommend to:

Check api-server logs

```
kubectl logs -f kube-apiserver-master -n kube-system
```

You should see something like:

```
Resetting endpoints for master service "kubernetes" to [10.156.0.3]
```

If you don't see it, try to manually remove etcd key for this service

Because the current state of the cluster is stored in etcd, it may happen that the key remain when you deleted a service:

a. exec to etcd-master pods

```
kubectl exec -it etcd-master -n kube-system sh
```

b. get the etcd key value

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt get /registry/services/endpoints/default/kubernetes
```

c. if you get any value like:

```
v1    Endpointst
O

kubernetesdefault"*$eafc04cf-90f3-11e9-a75e-42010a9c00032����z!


10.156.0.3
https�2TCP"
```

just remove it by

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt rm /registry/services/endpoints/default/kubernetes
```

After you did it, check the api-server logs once again.

Answer (score -1):

ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl delete all --all
service "kubernetes" deleted
ubuntu@master:~$ kubectl get svc
Command 'kubernetes' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install kubernetes
ubuntu@master:~$ sudo apt install kubernetes
ran the installation and it was restored.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).